# Equation display in Source Mode in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

It seems that overleaf displays some equations automatically in the Source text, as shown below:
[image]

(I am referring to the second and fourth lines). How can I have everything displayed in terms of $$ ?

** Update:
I just want to say that I am not in Rich mode text (I never use it). I am in source mode and lately (perhaps I changed some setting), I get my equations displayed in the source mode text. 
[image]

In addition, when I am editing the 'faulty' lines, I do get everything in LATEX code, but for a brief period of time (it then switches back to the displayed version).

[image]

Comment: Is it a case of it showing inline equations (using single "$") and not showing stand-alone equations (using double "$")?

Comment: You're probably looking at the document within the "Rich text" view, not the "Source" view, correct?

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf Support here. My first guess is that @Werner is correct: this looks like the RIch Text mode. The switch between Source / RIch Text is directly above the editor. If this does not solve the issue, feel free to reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: note that you should not have `$$` in latex

Comment: @Werner I am in the Source mode. I'll try to upload an additional picture in the main question.

Comment: Found the problem :D. I had installed a chrome extension on LATEX and it was somehow converting LATEX code to displayed equations. Once I deleted it everything switched back to normal. Thank you for your answers. I really appreciated.

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis You could answer your own question for future users with the same problem

Comment: @CarLaTeX Will do. Thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LATEX chrome extension was the cause of the issue as it was automatically displaying equations in LATEX form with the source text. By deactivating or deleting it from [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/) should fix the problem.